# Using Python combinations in multilevel data

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations

I have a dictionary, `imageHashes` with `keys=paths`, and `values = integers`, e.g.

```
imageHashes['/directorya/jim.txt'] = 7
imageHashes['/directorya/nigel.txt'] = 68
imageHashes['/directoryb/ralph.txt'] = 17
imageHashes['/directoryb/baba.txt'] = 43
```

Using combinations, I can loop through this  using:

```
for keypair in list(combinations(imageHashes,2)):
    do something
```

Problem is I only want to do the something between pairs in different directories, so between

- `jim` and `ralph`
- `nigel` and `ralph`
- `jim` and `baba`
- `nigel` and `baba` 
  **NOT**
- `jim` and `nigel`
- `ralph` and `baba`. 
  I'm a bit of a noob so can anyone tell me the best way of starting this?

Comment: The number of different directories in the pathds in `imageHashes` is always two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to overthink it: just iterate through the combinations and skip the ones you don't want to handle by using `continue`. The other thing you need to know is how to check if two files are in the same directory -- in other words, do the names of their directories match? This is what `os.path.dirname` gives us.

```
from itertools import combinations
from os.path import dirname

imageHashes = {}
imageHashes['/directorya/jim.txt'] = 7
imageHashes['/directorya/nigel.txt'] = 68
imageHashes['/directoryb/ralph.txt'] = 17
imageHashes['/directoryb/baba.txt'] = 43


for path_a, path_b in combinations(imageHashes, 2):
    if dirname(path_a) == dirname(path_b):
        continue

    print("They're different!: {} vs. {}".format(path_a, path_b))
```

Which gives:

```
They're different!: /directoryb/baba.txt vs. /directorya/jim.txt
They're different!: /directoryb/baba.txt vs. /directorya/nigel.txt
They're different!: /directorya/jim.txt vs. /directoryb/ralph.txt
They're different!: /directorya/nigel.txt vs. /directoryb/ralph.txt
```

Note that there ain't no need to convert the iterator returned by `combinations` to a list: that just wastes time.

Comment: It's easy when you know how! Many thanks, works great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general way of doing this, that is, having any number of directories:

```
from itertools import product

# get the set of different directories
dirs = {path.rsplit('/', 1)[0] for path in imageHashes}
# get iterators for every directory
dirs_iter = [[path for path in imageHashes if path.startswith(dir)] for dir in dirs]
# and now every possible combination between them
for comb in product(*dirs_iter):
    do something
```

Now `comb` would have as many elements as different directories in the available paths; that is, each `comb` would have one path of each of the directories.