# Unexpected result with filter or generators

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator-expression

Here's a funny one. I was actually writing an answer for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510146/using-python-combinations-in-multilevel-data) when I found some unexpected result using `filter` or generator. I have a list of file paths:

```
paths = ['/directoryb/baba.txt', '/directorya/nigel.txt', '/directoryb/ralph.txt', '/directorya/jim.txt'
```

I make the set of different directories in the paths list:

```
from os.path import dirname
dirs = {dirname(path) for path in paths}
```

And now I want to make a list of generators (or even a generator of generators), each one containing the elements of `paths` in the same directory. And so I do:

```
dirs_iter = [(path for path in paths if path.startswith(dir)) for dir in dirs]
```

Wasn't I surprised after running:

```
for dir_iter in dirs_iter:
    for path in dir_iter:
        print(path)
```

And obtaining the following:

```
/directorya/nigel.txt
/directorya/jim.txt
/directorya/nigel.txt
/directorya/jim.txt
```

This is clearly wrong. And yet, if I use the following sentence:

```
# now I'm generating the lists instead of using generators
dirs_iter = [[path for path in paths if path.startswith(dir)] for dir in dirs]
```

The printing loop shows the expected answer:

```
/directoryb/baba.txt
/directoryb/ralph.txt
/directorya/nigel.txt
/directorya/jim.txt
```

If I use `filter` and/or `map` instead of generators:

```
dirs_iter = map(lambda dir: filter(lambda path: path.startswith(dir), paths), dirs)
```

<s>I get the wrong answer too</s> **EDIT:** The `map`/`filter` version actually works.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `dir` is a closure and looked up *when executing the generator*, not when defining it. By that time `dir` was last bound to the last value in `dirs`:

```
>>> from os.path import dirname
>>> paths = ['/directoryb/baba.txt', '/directorya/nigel.txt', '/directoryb/ralph.txt', '/directorya/jim.txt']
>>> dirs = {dirname(path) for path in paths}
>>> def echo(value):
...     print('echoing:', value)
...     return value
... 
>>> dirs_iter = [(path for path in paths if path.startswith(echo(dir))) for dir in dirs]
>>> for dir_iter in dirs_iter:
...     print('Iterating over the next dir_iter generator')
...     for path in dir_iter:
...         print(path)
... 
Iterating over the next dir_iter generator
echoing: /directoryb
/directoryb/baba.txt
echoing: /directoryb
echoing: /directoryb
/directoryb/ralph.txt
echoing: /directoryb
Iterating over the next dir_iter generator
echoing: /directoryb
/directoryb/baba.txt
echoing: /directoryb
echoing: /directoryb
/directoryb/ralph.txt
echoing: /directoryb
>>> list(dirs)
['/directorya', '/directoryb']
```

Because Python 3 uses a random hash seed, in my run `/directoryb` was last rather than `/directorya`, but you can see that only when we actually *iterated* over the `dir_iter` generator that the `dir` value is accessed (and echoed), and that at that time it is set to one value. The `list(dirs)` line shows in what order the `dirs` set is yielding its values.

Note that `filter()` does **not** have this problem; your `map()` and `filter()` combo works just fine:

```
>>> dirs_iter = map(lambda dir: filter(lambda path: path.startswith(dir), paths), dirs)
>>> for dir_iter in dirs_iter:
...     for path in dir_iter:
...         print(path)
... 
/directorya/nigel.txt
/directorya/jim.txt
/directoryb/baba.txt
/directoryb/ralph.txt
```